# Rock Pit Drain, pumping up to neighbor

Tags: foundation, sump-pump, well-pump, water-damage, french-drain

My neighbour built a new home, and a laneway home, 4 years ago. I believe he has a rock pit under the back house, and drain tile leading forward to the road (city) for the front. 
I have been experiencing water pooling in the winter,all around my garage. Knee deep, in a garden bed. 
We have soggy land, mossy grass, and cracks in all our concrete. For the past 2 years. 
We dug a trench all along our foundation to see what was happening. we discovered, a 4 inch, perforated pipe,(holes on bottom only), capped, coming from under his laneway house.

This pipe would be on a upward slant from his back house, toward mine. 
Is it possible, he is pumping the water up, and draining under my garage? 
His laneway house is slab on grade, but his front house, is easily 12-15 in ground.
Im wondering if this pipe is an overflow of sorts, to keep his basement from flooding?

Yes the pipe is on my land, and I realize that issue, but Im really wanting to know if he was adding water. 
My plumbers think its an overflow, and the engineer I spoke to said it could be drainage for his wall.

Comment: In some locations you could cap the pipe at the edge of your land as he does not have the right to drain onto your property, but IANAL - you should get professional advice. It may be that Rylands v Fletcher is relevant...

Comment: Sounds like a basis for suing for damages. How did he install this pipe on your land without your knowledge?